WCF service accepting documents of any size locally. But when other systems are consuming it- giving me error 413- Request Entity too large error
I have a WCF service which is accepting documents of any size locally. But when other systems are consuming it or hitting it from Postman, giving me 413- Request Entity too large error. I tried all solutions related to Web config but no success. I am not sure from where the error is occurring from ASP.net or web server or any firewall. From Postman, the code is never hitting, it is breaking even before reaching the method. We are sending file contents using base64 string and accepting it in string parameter. We are using asp.net 4.0
I have already tried all solutions related to web config.

You can set Content-length in the header settings of the postman. I think you can set a relatively large value here to test.

Thanks for answering. I tried this but didn't work.
